# Adding a line with many points with Kinetic js

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am trying to add a line in a KineticJS stage. Line starts from point (0, 180) and extends straight choosing multiple x'es that differ by 5. That is my following code

```
var redInitialPoints = []
x = 0;
i = 0;
while (x+i<=stage.width()){
    redInitialPoints.push(x+i);
    redInitialPoints.push(stage.y()+18*10);
    i += 5;
}

redLine1 = new Kinetic.Line({
    point:redInitialPoints,
    stroke:'red',
    strokeWidth:2,
    id:"redLine1"

linesGroup.add(redLine1);  //this is what causes the issue
//backGroundLayer.add(redLine1) works fine
```

The reason I want to have so many points is because I want my line according to some input to go up and down like a cardiogram and to have some peeks and the opposite, but still to look like one line.

```
________________________
```

and becomes

```
             __   
__/\____/\__/  \
```

etc.

But I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

What can be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If `stage` is of type `Kinetic.Stage`, the [documentation](http://kineticjs.com/docs/Kinetic.Stage.html) says that you should use `stage.getWidth()` and `stage.getY()` instead of `stage.width()` and `stage.y()`. Maybe that will fix the problem.